# Calibration data selection - basic rules

Tags: options, market-data, calibration

Hey I found following rules for selecting data for calibration (source: "Kou Jump Diffusion Model: An Application to the Standard and
Poor 500, Nasdaq 100 and Russell 2000 Index Options" by Wajih Abbasi1
, Petr Hájek
, Diana Ismailova
, Saira Yessimzhanova
, Zouhaier Ben Khelifa
,
Kholnazar Amonov):

> The final sample is obtained by applying five filters. First, all the
> options with an average price <50 cents were removed. Then the options
> with a spread which is the difference between the ask price and bid
> price divided by the mid-price of this option, where that spread
> represents more than 50% of the average call price are removed. These
> first two filters are meant to eliminate calls with a large spread in
> relation to bid-ask quotations reported by the database. **We also
> removed options with a moneyness which deviates from the range (−10%,
> 10%).** Indeed, the options that are  deep out-of-the-money (OTM) or
> deep-in-the-money (ITM) are illiquid and have a low time value which
> substantially affects the predictive power of the estimated parameters
> value. **Next, we eliminated options with <6 days or over 100 days to
> expiration**. The former have almost zero time premiums while the latter
> are illiquid. **Finally, all options that do not meet the noarbitrage
> assumption are eliminated.** The majority of observations eliminated
> correspond to deep ITM calls.

I have some questions:

1. In the case of moneyness we need to have $\frac{|\rm{strike}-S_0|}{S_0}\le0.1$ right?
2. Is it okay that we remove all options with maturity longer than 100 days?
3. How to check which options do not meet the noarbitrage assumpion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $S_t$ is the underlier price at time $t$ and $K$ is the strike price, the percent moneyness is $\frac{S_t-K}{K}$ for a call and $\frac{K-S_t}{K}$ for a put. Otherwise, the percentages for puts and calls would be confusing. A put option on the stock of a bankrupt firm (so $S_t=0$) should be 100% in-the-money. If we divided by $S_t$, the percent moneyness would be infinite. Sinilarly, dividing by $S_t$ for a call option means that a deep-in-the-money option could never be 100% in-the-money even if the underlier were 100$\times K$.

Removing options with maturities over 100 days means keeping only the near-to-expiry quarterly options as well as the next-to-expire options once within a couple weeks of them becoming the near-to-expiry options. This is very reasonable and smart because it prevents the analysis from being skewed by less liquid options.

How to check if an option does not meet no-arbitrage assumptions? First, if put-call parity does not hold, the put and call jointly fail the no-arbitrage assumption. Also, an option should be worth more than $PV[\max(0,S_t-K)]$ (for calls) or $PV(\max(0,K-S_t)]$ (for puts).